# Install PyAudio with WinPython

Tags: python, pyaudio

On Windows 7, I want to install PyAudio to use with WinPython, but the PyAudio installer crashes out because there is no Python entry in the registry. WinPython does a lot of things its own way so I'm not surprised installing it doesn't set up the registry in the same way installing a regular version of Python does. Anyway, what can I do?

Using Python 3.3.2 as part of the WinPython installation.

Having another problem:

I followed the suggestions to register WinPython with Windows 7, and then installed PyAudio, which went fine until I tried to run "import pyaudio" at which point it exited, saying "Please Build and Install the PortAudio Python Bindings first." My intention is not to have to build anything, and the PyAudio installer web page says it includes PortAudio V19.

Further information: I noticed that the installer for PyAudio says "32 bit only" and I suspect my version of WinPython was "built for 64 bit" (not sure what that means, but the installation directory is c:\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.2)

Answer (score 0):

Install Python 3.3.5 (32Bit) and then install PyAudio with the windows installer.

It works at my PC (Win7 x64).